# Installing Passenger on CentOS 6.0 with the view to running my Puppet Master via Passenger

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, puppetmaster

I'm attempting to configure Puppet to run via Passenger. I'm using this [guide](http://www.tomhayman.co.uk/linux/install-puppet-passenger-centos-6-part/)

I've hit a bit of a brick wall. When I attempt to reload apache, I get the following error:

```
[Sun Jul 15 19:38:44 2012] [error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/domain.name.pem
[Sun Jul 15 19:38:44 2012] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Sun Jul 15 19:38:44 2012] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

Currently I ave the following options in the conf file

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite SSLv2:-LOW:-EXPORT:RC4+RSA
```

The path is correct, and the certificate is there. When I run Puppet via the inbuilt webrick  it runs okay.

Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the SSL config that you've set in Apache?

Comment: SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite SSLv2:-LOW:-EXPORT:RC4+RSA

Comment: Edit your question to include the additional information - it doesn't fit well or format well in a comment.

Comment: Does the user which Apache runs as have read access to the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you double checked the paths tot he certificates? It could be possible that your backups contained the wrong paths

Comment: DAMN! I've been working on old config files - updated the paths, and all working fine!